# cocos2d move an object from one point to another thorugh Bézier Curves

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to move an object from one point to another (just like Flight Control HD game) through Bézier curves; does anyone have any ideas? I found [a tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6099) on cocos2d but I can't figure out Bézier Curves, any idea about this thing??

Answer (score 0):

There is an cocos2d example project that helps you calculate the bezier points and shows you how to make them.

http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=798